# Safari can't recognize date, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send a date to the backend in this format - **"yyyy-mm-dd"**

*Chrome sees the date, but the safari doesn't*

```
  handleDateChange = e => {
    let inputDate = e.target.value // 10/10/1997
    const splited = inputDate.split('/')
    const swaped = [splited[1], splited[0], splited[2]]
    const swappedDate = new Date(swaped)

    const day = swappedDate.getDate()
    const month = swappedDate.getMonth() + 1
    const year = swappedDate.getFullYear()

    const toISO = `${year}-${month.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + month : month}-${day}`

    console.log(toISO) // Chromium - 1997-10-10 // Safari - NaN-NaN-NaN

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: toISO,
      bannerText: '',
      birthDate: e.target.value,
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) can handle an array of strings? If this works in Chrome you're just lucky.

Comment: And why the de-tour with `new Date(swaped)` at all? `day = splited[1]; month = splited[0]; year = splited[2];`

Comment: I need the date to start with the day, in this format - dd / mm / yyyy, but safari doesn't like that ...

Comment: The explanation why and the solution is already in the comments